# PySimpleGUI, For the life of me I can't figure out why my vertical separator isn't working

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am learning Python and I cannot figure out why my vertical separator isn't working. I've followed guides, videos, and I am sure it's something simple, but I can't figure it out.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

#Adding the Theme
sg.theme('SystemDefault')

#Determining the List
list1 = ('Pennsylvania', 'Texas', 'California')

#Left Layout, Data Entry

Leftlayout = [
    [sg.Text('Offer Letter Generator', justification='center', size=(900,1))],
    [sg.Text('Position', size =(10,1)), sg.InputText('')],
    [sg.Text('Work Location', size=(10,1)), sg.Combo(values=list1, default_value=list1[0])],
    [sg.Text('Start Date', size=(10,1)), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text('Manager Name', size=(10, 1)), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text('Manager Title', size=(10, 1)), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text('Salary', size=(10, 1)), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Checkbox('Profit Sharing?', default=False)],
    [sg.Text('Vaction', size=(10, 1)), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text('',size=(20,15))],
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]
]

#Assigning Right Layout

RightLayout = [
    [sg.Text('PDF Preview', size=(20,15))]
]

#Final Layout for Use
Finallayout = [
    [
        sg.Column(Leftlayout),
        sg.VSeperator(color='blue'),
        sg.Column(RightLayout),
    ]
]

#GUI Window
window = sg.Window('Offer Generator', Finallayout,size=(900,500))
event, values = window.read()
window.close()
```

This is my first time posting on here, so I think I did this right in terms of formatting my question

[Vertical Separator Not Appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjGOd.png)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "isn't working"?

Comment: I just added a photo to clarify, sorry.

Comment: The separator and the right frame not shown in a narrow window where there's one Text element in left frame with same width as it of your window.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It is spelt `sg.VSeparator`, not `sg.VSeperator` (as you currently have).</strike>

**Edit:** (taken from my comment): Do you think the fact that your window width is 900 and the width of `sg.Text('Offer Letter Generator', justification='center', size=(900,1))` is also set at 900 means that the the left column is consuming the entire window. Shouldn't the window be made wider or the element narrower?

Comment: I made that change, and it didn't affect anything since PySimpleGUI has both spellings for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried strictly defining a size? Has it got anything to do with the fact that the right column is empty?

Comment: I just added some additional fields, and it seems the entire right side isn't even drafting. Would it be something I have to use "Justification" for?

Comment: Maybe try ```sg.VSeparator(pad = (0,0))```?

Comment: Nothing either. It seems like the entire right column isn't being shown, I feel like that might have something to do with it? Maybe?

Comment: Do you think the fact that your window width is 900 and the width of ```[sg.Text('Offer Letter Generator', justification='center', size=(900,1))]``` is set at 900 means that the the left column is consuming the entire window. Shouldn't the window be made wider or the element narrower?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your help! I overlooked the obvious issue!

I had a massive "Offer Letter Generator" X value as way too high. I didn't think about what I was doing. Moving the X value of that text fixed all of my issues.

Comment: This is not an answer, please write your comments on the section below your question.